Rendering Imperfections
A newbie question: I'm rendering a very simple scene that imitates a coordinate system. The axes are Grease Pencil line art attached to a cube with 4 vertices and then for each XY/YZ/XZ I created a plane (there is another parallelogram but I don't think it plays any role here) and positioned exactly at the coordinate planes. Now, when I render this, due to some rendering imperfections part of Z axis is not visible, it looks like the plane on the right obstructs it somehow (which it shouldn't if basic geometry plays any role here). How do I make it render correctly?
Update: rendered the scene without the vertical planes, showing the axes.




Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

"Line art" is not a precise thing in Blender. How were the axes made? With Grease Pencil, I assume?

Please add a shot of the axes showing up correctly (assumably would be with the right plane removed).

@TheLabCat yes Greased pencil. I added the shot you asked. Thanks.
